# R: comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r

I am getting the error in the subject line for the following piece of code in R.

```
r<- matrix(c(2,4, 1,5,5,3, 4,5,1,2,3,4), nrow=3)
for (u in 1:nrow(r))
  for (x in 1:ncol(r))
    r_hat<- function(u,x) {


      if (r_hat >r[u,x]) {
        print(r[u,x]-r_hat)
      }
    }
```

How can I get rid of the error?

Comment: It works fine for me! Try running it line by line, that can be a good way to debug code like this!

Answer (score 2):

The code works and leads to no error. The result is a definition of one variable `r`and one function `r_hat`.

You get the same with this snippet (I removed the loop as not relevant, what you do is creating the same function repeatedly in a loop)

```
> r<- matrix(c(2,4, 1,5,5,3, 4,5,1,2,3,4), nrow=3)
> 
> r_hat<- function(u,x) {
+       if (r_hat >r[u,x]) {
+         print(r[u,x]-r_hat)
+       }
+ }
```

The problem is in the function, after calling it you get the mentioned error.

```
> r_hat(0,0)   
Error in r_hat > r[u, x] : 
  comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types
>
```

You reference `r_hat` within the function, are you trying to define a recursive function? Than the recursive call should have the parameters and the function some return value...

My guess is you tries to compare the *function definition* with an element of a matrix, which leads to this error.

If this is not enough for you and you explains what the code should deliver, I'll try to complete my answer.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your response. I am actually trying to code the algorithm given on page 4 of this paper: http://www.machinelearning.org/proceedings/icml2004/papers/221.pdf . You are right, i get the error while calling the function.

Comment: @UD1989 I'd suggest to post a dedicated question on this task. Possible on SO with R tag. In my understanding the main challenge is to find implementation that doesn't use for loop but is vectorized; i.e. the function `f` returns a vector of result for all ratings. You should simplify the requirements by avoiding the iteration loop and provide the initial data.frame and the function `F` in some trivial implementation. I guess this could be a very interesting question. I have some solution, but possible far from optimal one, so let me know:)

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing the same problem but i cant figure out what is what
Date                Original_Forecast Residual_Forecast Dispatchable_Generat…¹
                                                         
1 2019-04-01 00:00:00 NA                           20127.                 21035.
2 2019-04-01 01:00:00 NA                           19822.                 20548.
3 2019-04-01 02:00:00 NA                           19726.                 20413.
4 2019-04-01 03:00:00 NA                           19939.                 20476.
5 2019-04-01 04:00:00 NA                           20794.                 21156.
6 2019-04-01 05:00:00 NA                           22703.                 23079.

## ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​Dispatchable_Generation

## ℹ 7 more variables: Residual_Demand , MLR , Installed ,

## PCLF , UCLF , OCLF , UCLF_OCLF

> 

res = cosinor(MLR ~ 1, date = Date,

- data = load_2, type = 'hourly',
- family = poisson(), offsetmonth = TRUE)

Error in names(data) == date :
comparison (==) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/88821)